# Running espresso tests without reinstalling application

Tags: android-espresso

I'm running "gradlew connectedCheck" to run espresso test on installed app, but this "gradlew connectedCheck" rewrites my app and then runs tests.
How can I run espresso tests without reinstalling my app?

Comment: We are developing-building all the apps with Eclipse + maven. And now I'm trying to jump to UI testing with Espresso but all the examples is going with Android Studio + gradle. The first idea is to write Espresso UI tests with Android Studio, but apk for UI testing to take from Eclipse output. The migration to Android Studio is not started yet. So the UI tests we are planning to do with with Android Studio now.

Comment: I guess it is obvious for developers, but for testers...
With Espresso app apk and test apk are installed separate and I checked test apk name in device. In my case is "com.example.romas.sum3.test" with the ending "test" and this ending "test" confusing me, because package is "com.example.romas.sum3".
And now I can run tests separate with command:
'adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.example.romas.sum3.ApplicationTest com.example.romas.sum3.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

Comment: You can run tests with existing apks using `adb shell am instrument -w <test_package_name>/<runner_class>` This does not install or uninstall you apks. For More details and examples see http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html

Answer (score -3):

gradle will check if there is any code change since the last build and run of the test but if there is no change in the code it will not reinstall the app.

Comment: Downvoted because I still get symptoms of uninstalling (empty getFilesDir() folder) even if I don't change any source between runs